# Usage of special characters in the URL path instead of query-strings to allow relative linking in a web proxy

Tags: url, proxy, query-string, path

I've received complaints that the links that my software is generating aren't following the W3C URL-specification. http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

The links generated looks like this: `https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/https://www.google.com/`

The software is a proxy and generates the links this way so that the proxy doesn't have to parse relative links. Examples: `/maps/`, `../relative_link`.

Using a solution that uses query-string wouldn't allow this.

Is my usage correct of constructing the URL correct or should I URL encode everything after `/proxive/`?

I can add that my solution works in all major browsers.

Comment: If you encode everything after/proxive then will W3c allow it?

Comment: Well that is my question. "Is my usage correct of constructing the URL correct or should I URL encode everything after `/proxive/`?"

Comment: A bit of an aside, but I'm curious... why wouldn't "a solution that uses query-string .. allow this"? Isn't what you are doing essentially the same as a query string, as I assume you are manually parsing the URL and passing this path segment to your application? (You could even be URL rewriting this URL to one with a query string?)

Comment: Since if a user clicks a relative link it will ignore the path in the query string. Example: User is on `https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/?url=https://www.google.com/` and clicks a relative link to `./hello/world/`. The user ends up on `https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/hello/world/` instead of `https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/?url=https://www.google.com/hello/world/`

Comment: Ah I see, but how do you handle the situation when an alternative `BASE` URL has been specified in the document? (Or a root-relative URL like @StephenOstermiller mentions - unless perhaps your proxy works in the root of your site?)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the only thing that you would *need* to escape in that URL would be the `:`

```
https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/https%3A//www.google.com/
```

Then your URL wouldn't use any disallowed characters and the directories would still be on the sub URL for supporting some relative links.

---

I just want to point out that not *all* relative links will work. I usually code my sites to work with *site relative* URLs like `/img/logo.png`   When used on `http://example.com/dir/page.html` it will fetch the relative URL `http://example.com/img/logo.png`.

So in your case if you tried to proxy `http://example.com/dir/page.html` it would end up fetching `https://organization.proxive.se/img/logo.png`

Comment: "you would need to escape ... the `:`" - although I believe a `:` is valid in a _path segment_ in an absolute URL. In fact all chars would seem to be valid in the _path_ part. However, I think the confusion lies in the use of the slash, in what is essentially a single _path segment_? The slash is the _path segment_ delimiter, so cannot be unescaped in a single _path segment_. The `https://www.google.com/` part is really one path segment, as it is being read by the proxy, however, any other system parsing the URL would see this as an additional 3 (maybe 4) path segments on the parent URL. (?)

Comment: So, _I think_, the URL should perhaps (more correctly) be expressed as: `https://organization.proxive.se/proxive/https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F` (?)

Comment: He wants to preserve the slashes in the URL so that some relative URLs work.

Comment: The proxy knows how to handle relative urls starting with "/". The proxy also knows how to handle if the browser sends one slash instead of the doubleslash in the url. So if the : symbol is valid then I don't have to change anything I guess?!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, that should still preserve the slashes, just as encoding the colon will preserve the colon - this URL still needs to be parsed (inc. unescaped) by the proxy, which I assume is what's happening. (Although admittedly, by default, on Apache an encoded slash in the path part will result in an instant 404, so would perhaps need to look into the [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive if deciding to go this route.)

Comment: @emilhem Yes, I don't think you necessarily need to change anything. It would be interesting to hear the "complaints" of others who believe this is breaking the specification - and why this is a concern? As mentioned above, as far as I can see, it's just the interpretation of the path segments that could throw someone - but why this would be a problem I don't know.